# EasySearch meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

is it possible to change the button loadmore of the easySearch search package by a spinner? Giving you style?
According to the documentation can give the style, I have tried to make it work, but so far I have not been successful.

```
{{> EasySearch.LoadMore index=myIndex content="Load more content"}}
```

> Parameters
>
> content: The content of the button attributes: Object with the button
>   attributes (e.g. { class: "load-more-button" })
>   count: Number of documents to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will not be able to change from a 'button' to a 'spinner' because the `EasySearch.LoadMore` component literally renders an HTML button element (see below taken from the EasySearch [source](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/blob/master/packages/easysearch:components/lib/load-more/load-more.html)).

```
<template name="EasySearch.LoadMore">
    {{#if moreDocuments}}
        <button {{attributes}}>{{content}}</button>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Even though you cannot change to a spinner, you can at least style the 'button' using the `attributes` argument (which you mentioned in your question).  To do this, just pass an object that contains a `class` property.  Since you cannot define object literals in spacebars, you will have to create a template helper to do this (as I have shown in the below example).

```
Template.mySearch.helpers({
  loadMoreAttributes: function() {
    return {
      class: "load-more-button"
    }
  },
});
```

Then use your helper in your template like this.

```
{{> EasySearch.LoadMore index=myIndex content="Load more content" attributes=loadMoreAttributes}}
```

This will give your "load more" button a css class of `load-more-button`.  Then you can just style it in css like the example below.  Obviously, you will use the styling that you want...this is purely for example.

```
.load-more-button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for answer let me try to see how it goes, load-more-button class I call from the css and there directly I give the style right? @jordanwillis

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer to give an example of css styling.

Comment: Very grateful for the help, regards @jordanwillis

Comment: I was able to get the spinner, thanks again for the help